# MySQL Grouping similar rows based on entries in a second table

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping

I really didn't know what to title this.

I have a few tables structured like this

A "sentences" table

```
id |    sentence       | ...
----------------------------
1  | See Spot run      | ...
2  | See Jane run      | ...
3  | Jane likes cheese | ...
```

A "words" table

```
id | word (unique)
----------
1  | See
2  | Spot
3  | run
4  | Jane
5  | likes
6  | cheese
```

And a "word_references" table

```
sentence_id | word_id
---------------------
          1 | 1 
          1 | 2
          1 | 3
          2 | 1
          2 | 3
          2 | 4
          3 | 4
          3 | 5
          3 | 6
```

I want to return a list of sentences pairs that are similar to each other based on shared words ordered by similarlity. So it should return:

```
one | two | similarity
----------------------
 1  |  2  |  2
 2  |  3  |  1
```

because sentences 1 and 2 share two words: "See" and "run", while sentences 2 and 3 share one word: "Jane".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should solve your problem:

```
SELECT r1.sentence_id AS one, 
       r2.sentence_id AS two, 
       Count(*)       AS similarity 
FROM   word_references r1 
       INNER JOIN word_references r2 
               ON r1.sentence_id < r2.sentence_id 
                  AND r1.word_id = r2.word_id 
GROUP  BY r1.sentence_id, 
          r2.sentence_id
```

this gives:

```
one | two | similarity
----------------------
 1  |  2  |  2
 2  |  3  |  1
```

sqlfiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/332bc1/19/0)

If you change the expression `r1.sentence_id < r2.sentence_id` to `r1.sentence_id <> r2.sentence_id`, you'll get both sides of the relation:

```
one | two | similarity
----------------------
 1  |  2  |  2
 2  |  3  |  1
 2  |  1  |  2
 3  |  2  |  1
```

Comment: To make it somewhat neater and possibly faster: use `inner join` instead of `left join`, put both conditions `r1.sentence_id<r2.sentence_id` and `r1.word_id=r2.word_id` in the `join`. Add `order by similarity desc` to show most similar results at the top.

Comment: Works great. Its pretty slow but thats to be expected when doing an O(n^2) operation in my environment. I wonder if there's any index that could be added or another table that might speed things up.

Comment: @MarkMurfin I guess your word_references table has a composite primary key (sentence_id,word_id); I'd try adding two indexes one on each column.

Comment: @MarkMurfin, @guido, I think the composite index in `word_references` should be on `word_id` first, then on `sentence_id`, because you compare `word_id` for equality first, then `sentence_id` for range. Also try different variants with `ASC`, `DESC` in index and order of conditions in the `join`. It should not matter, but I would check. It would not help much, though, the overall algorithm is still `O(n*n)` and I don't think you can avoid it - you want all pairs of sentences... On the other hand... How does your data look like: few long sentences or many short sentences?

Comment: My data consists of many long sentences. Well, by long I guess average 7-10 words, with some as few as three words, and some as many as 20. They are actually news headlines pulled from RSS feeds. When you follow certain blogs, especially tech blogs, they all tend to write about the same topic around the same time. I'm working on a way to group articles together and combined with some other data, show the user the article they are most likely to read/enjoy.

Comment: @MarkMurfin, you should include the name of the user in comments, so that he receives a notification. My idea was to build all pairs of **sentences**, rather than all pairs of `word_references` as it is done in this query. And then for each pair of sentences calculate its similarity. There must be much less pairs of sentences, than pairs of words. So, overall performance may be better. But you are using MySQL. I don't know how to write an efficient query of this style in MySQL. In SQL Server I'd try to use `CROSS APPLY`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work:

```
select w1.sentence_id, w2.sentence_id, count(*) as similarity
from word_references w1 
left join word_references w2 on  w1.word_id=w2.word_id and w1.sentence_id<>w2.sentence_id
where w2.sentence_id is not null
group by w1.sentence_id, w2.sentence_id 
order by count(*) desc
```

Sample output:

```
+ ---------------- + ---------------- + --------------- +
| sentence_id      | sentence_id      | similarity      |
+ ---------------- + ---------------- + --------------- +
| 1                | 2                | 2               |
| 2                | 1                | 2               |
| 3                | 2                | 1               |
| 2                | 3                | 1               |
+ ---------------- + ---------------- + --------------- +
4 rows
```